# NameError: name 'Pick' is not defined

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I am a learning the if statement by creating a rock, paper, scissors game with Tkinter. I'm trying to make a label that will appear if a button is pressed. so for example it will put a label saying "rock" if i press the rock button. But I have a problem in the if statement. This is what I have

```
import random
from tkinter import *

click = True

def compick():
    choice = random.choice(["rock","paper","scissors"])
    return choice

compchoice = compick()

def yourChoice(Pick):
    global click

br = Button(gui, image=img1, command= lambda:yourChoice('rock'))
br.place(x=15, y=100)
bp = Button(gui, image=img2, command= lambda:yourChoice('paper'))
bp.place(x=200 ,y=100)
bs = Button(gui, image=img3, command= lambda:yourChoice('scissors'))
bs.place(x=350, y=100)

if click==True:
    if Pick =='rock':
        LR.place(x=225, y=500)
        if compchoice =='rock':
            LR.place(x=225, y=15)

gui.mainloop()
```

It gave me an error saying  "name 'Pick' is not defined". I have no idea what's wrong with the code.

Comment: I'm guessing those if-statements towards the end are supposed to be in the body of the `yourChoice` function. If that is the case, you'll have to properly indent them, as well as the previous lines, so that they are part of the body of the function.

Comment: indentation is very important in python. Your function `yourChoice` only contains a singular line. I think you're supposed to put everything after `yourChoice` (up until the `mainloop()`) inside the function, So you have to indent it out. Please read the basic tutorial at the very least - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: It looks like there're lot of issues in your script, not complete executable script. first you should get error 'gui' is not defined;  command in Button defined wrong function, maybe just None, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent your function definition :

```
def yourChoice(Pick):
    global click

    br = Button(gui, image=img1, command= lambda:yourChoice('rock'))
    br.place(x=15, y=100)
    bp = Button(gui, image=img2, command= lambda:yourChoice('paper'))
    bp.place(x=200 ,y=100)
    bs = Button(gui, image=img3, command= lambda:yourChoice('scissors'))
    bs.place(x=350, y=100)

    if click==True: # <-- Be careful, you set it to True just before ! 
        if Pick =='rock':
            LR.place(x=225, y=500)
            if compchoice =='rock':
                LR.place(x=225, y=15)
```

Also, the following code might be useful for your implementation, it will makes you avoid the long if...else ugly structure :

```
choice ={
    "rock":0,
    "paper":1,
    "scissors":2
    }

result = {
    0:"It's a draw",
    1:"Player1 win",
    2:"Player2 win"
    }

def judge(player1_choice,player2_choice):
    P1=choice[player1_choice]
    P2=choice[player2_choice]
    return result[(P1-P2)%3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an indentation error. Place all your code for the function `yourChoice` under a single indent.

Something like this:

```
def yourChoice(Pick):
    global click

    br = Button(gui, image=img1, command= lambda:yourChoice('rock'))
    br.place(x=15, y=100)
    bp = Button(gui, image=img2, command= lambda:yourChoice('paper'))
    bp.place(x=200 ,y=100)
    bs = Button(gui, image=img3, command= lambda:yourChoice('scissors'))
    bs.place(x=350, y=100)

    if click==True:
        if Pick =='rock':
           LR.place(x=225, y=500)
            if compchoice =='rock':
                LR.place(x=225, y=15)
```

Now, all of the above mentioned code is executed when a call is made to the `yourChoice` function.

Answer (score 1):

Python is one of the few languages for which indents are actually significant. You could try adjusting the code's indentation after "global click" so that they match. Something like this:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

click = True

def compick():
    choice = random.choice(["rock","paper","scissors"])
    return choice

compchoice = compick()

def yourChoice(Pick):
    global click
    br = Button(gui, image=img1, command= lambda:yourChoice('rock'))
    br.place(x=15, y=100)
    bp = Button(gui, image=img2, command= lambda:yourChoice('paper'))
    bp.place(x=200 ,y=100)
    bs = Button(gui, image=img3, command= lambda:yourChoice('scissors'))
    bs.place(x=350, y=100)

    if click==True:
        if Pick =='rock':
            LR.place(x=225, y=500)
            if compchoice =='rock':
                LR.place(x=225, y=15)

gui.mainloop()
```